# Increase background image size with animate

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following code:

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kTewC/5/)

I want that on hover the background image too should get expanded i.e 200px X 200px. Is there a way to accomplish that?
**Without using CSS3**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or, this is supported buy any browser:

```
#background {
width: 100px; 
height: 100px; 
position: absolute; 
z-index: -1;
}

.backgroundimage {
width:100%;
height:100%;
}


<div id="background">
<img src="/path/to/background/image.gif" class="backgroundimage" alt="" />
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kTewC/13/

Answer (score 2):

CSS 3 background-size property? http://jsfiddle.net/kTewC/10/

Comment: ain't it possible to do it without using CSS 3?

Answer (score 0):

Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kTewC/14/), Here I have added stretch as CSS class, advantage is when mouseOut you can remove it if needed. This is based on @user1090389